# How to find out what's wrong with distributed transactions?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, transactions, msdtc

I have googled a lot the last days and checked data and the registry, but did not find a solution or even the root cause of the problem:

We have multiple WCF web services that talk to each other (and finally a SQL Server database) using distributed transactions as "Allowed" (not "Mandatory"). We have a Web Farm (2008R2, IIS7 with WFF) where on one node it works and on the other, it does not. Transactions are simply not routed through.

I wrote a test application that self-hosts a chain of three services that do nothing but calling each other. The last one returns true. This chain will have distributed transactions on one machine (as can be seen by printing out the distributed transaction ID) and no distributed transactions on the other. However, there are no errors. There simply is no transaction coming in.

I have checked the dialogs that open up when you call

> dcomcnfg.exe => Computer => MyComputer => Distributed Transaction Controller => Local DTC => Properties

and they are exactly the same on both machines. Just to make sure I exported the registry keys below `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC`. The only differences between the machines were the 
`KtmRmTmIdentifier` and the `XAKeyCNGKeyDataBlob` keys. Being different machines, I would have expected them to be different. All settings were the same.

Now with the very same binary executable working on one and failing on the other machine I strongly suspect our machine setup to be at fault but I'm really out of possible options where to look for differences or how to find out what's wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas what else I could check or what test I could run to find out what the problem is?

Additional Information:

The settings look like this:

[image: LocalDTCProperties]

Comment: It is a bit shot in the dark but do you active Network DTC access in security settings and in Transcation Manager Communication Allow Inbound, Allow Outbound. I had some problems in the past with transactions, which I don't remember anymore but this checkboxes in security tab fix the issue.

Comment: @mybirthname I updated the post with the current settings on both nodes. Right now, I'll take any hint, even guesses and shots in the dark because I'm out of ideas and it's not working :)

Comment: Looks like my shot miss :) I already up vote your question hope someone help you !

Comment: If you change your transaction from "Allowed" to "Mandatory" and retest it will fail with an exception/event log entry instead of silently.

Comment: Through more tests we found out it's only failing when we attach one of our message inspectors. Right now I don't know why, but at least it's a start for debugging and a workaround.

Comment: Any success in debugging, we are facing the same issue, any clues would be helpful

Comment: @scorpio It turned out that our code reacted differently on different machines due to debug configuration files on these machines. So nothing really that could be helpful to you, sorry :(

Comment: what do you mean by debug configuration files? perhaps that we need to check as well

Comment: @scorpio Sorry, my first comment was ambiguous. It were files our program checked and acted accordingly. Self-defined. Nothing standard.

Comment: oh okay.. it would be worth adding that in answer and closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue and found that BizTalk Adapter pack CU3 was missing, therefore the WCF Adapter was not working correctly.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2617150/cumulative-update-package-3-for-biztalk-adapter-pack-2010